# php CSV headers for columns

Tags: php, csv, header

I want to write the columns for a generated CSV file into PHP headers. I want the headers to be (name, surname, address).

Image Illustration:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
if (! empty ( $_POST ['csv'] )) 
{
   $this->prepareAckINS ( $rows, true ); 
   header ('Content-Type: text/csv; utf-8'); 
   header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . date ( 'Ymd_His' ) . '_ack.csv');
   $this->data ['csv'] = $rows ; 
   echo $this->loadAndSetView ('csv'); 
   exit (); 
}
```

Comment: the output are rows 1 2 3 , 1 2 3 , 1 2 3, I want tto put permanent headers on columns ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the .csv file into an array with [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), then create a new array, assigning the headers as the first entry, followed by writing all lines from the csv file to the new array. Finally, save your new CSV.

```
$oldcsv = file('sample.csv');
$csv = array();
$csv[] = "name,surname,address";
foreach($oldcsv as $v){
   $csv[] = $v;
}
```